# VB NET Read Remote Registry

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to get the architecture and the operating system of many remote pcs.
In order to do that i'm querying Win32_OperatingSystem and parsing the "Caption" for the O.S. and for the architecture im reading OSArchitecture .
In Windows XP this value does not exists, so i thought that reading the HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE
would have done the trick like this code:

```
            Try

            Dim co As New ConnectionOptions
            co.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate
            co.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy
            co.EnablePrivileges = True

            co.Username = username
            co.Password = password

            Dim scope As New ManagementScope("\\" & machine.Text & "\root\cimv2", co)

            scope.Connect()

            Dim environmentKey, asd2 As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey
            Dim asd As String

            environmentKey = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, machine.Text)
            asd2 = environmentKey.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment", True)
            asd = asd2.GetValue("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE")

            Debug.Print("asd: " + asd)

            environmentKey.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception

            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)

        End Try
```

My problem is: if im trying this code I get an System.Security.SecurityException: "Accessing remote registry not permitted"

I am, and i know the administrator username and password.
In fact if I run a simple  cmdkey /add:targetname /user:username /pass:password
It works.

So why do I have to run a cmdkey /add even if i have alredy specified the username and password in the ConnectionOptions ??

P.S. Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 1):

This may very well be because remote registry access is not enabled on the target PC.

Even if you know the administrator credentials, remote access to the registry will not work if the feature isn't enabled on the target PC.

To enable it, see the following Microsoft Knowledge Base Article, which covers a variety of Windows Operating Systems: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/314837

Comment: The service Remote Registry is alredy enabled in all remote pc.

Comment: Have you enabled remote registry access through the firewall? Did you verify that such access is enabled through group policy?

Comment: Yes, it is enabled, cause if it wasn't even if'd do cmdkey add woudln't work

Answer (score 1):

All right, i got it:
Const HKEY_current_user As String = "80000002"

```
    Dim options As New ConnectionOptions
    options.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate
    options.EnablePrivileges = True
    options.Username = ".\administrator"
    options.Password = "my_password"

    Dim myScope As New ManagementScope("\\" & RemotePCHostname & "\root\default", options)
    Dim mypath As New ManagementPath("StdRegProv")
    Dim mc As New ManagementClass(myScope, mypath, Nothing)

    Dim inParams As ManagementBaseObject = mc.GetMethodParameters("GetDWORDValue")
    inParams("hDefKey") =  UInt32.Parse(HKEY_current_user,System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber) 'RegistryHive.LocalMachine
    inParams("sSubKeyName") = "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"
    inParams("sValueName") = "PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE"

    Dim outParams As ManagementBaseObject = mc.InvokeMethod("GetStringValue", inParams, Nothing)

    If (outParams("ReturnValue").ToString() = "0") Then
        MessageBox.Show(outParams("sValue").ToString())
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Error retrieving value : " + outParams("ReturnValue").ToString())
    End If
```